# Javascript variable substitution for json

Tags: javascript, json, variables, substitution

Greetings all,

I have some JSON code that looks like this:

```
{ playlist: [ 
    'URL goes here', 
    { 
        // our song 
        url: 'another URL goes here'
    }
  ]  
}
```

I'd like to stick the value of a javascript variable into the JSON, and have it be substituted in place of 'URL goes here'.  Is there a way to do that in JSON?  I'm a noob at JSON so help would be much appreciated.  The value of the variable to substitute would come from something like getElementById().getAttribute().

Thanks,
NorthK

Comment: Please don't forget that what you call "JSON" is just JavaScript. You can use any valid JavaScript expression in JavaScript (of course, when serializing, you should stick to the subset allowed by standard "JSON".)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So I'm assuming that you have a json object called `jsonObject`:

```
var url = "http://example.com/";
jsonObject.playlist[0] = url;
```

On the other hand, if you're talking about construction the json object, then you just put the variable into the right position:

```
var url = "http://example.com/";
var jsonObject = {playlist: [ 
    url, 
    { 
        // our song 
        url: 'another URL goes here'
    }
  ]  
}
```

Note that there's no problem with `url` being used as a variable in our list, while also being used as a key in the object that comes right after it.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that JSON stands for Javascript Object Notation. It's just a way to encode objects into a string so you can pass it about easily (eg: over HTTP). In your code, it should have already been parsed into an object, therefore you can modify it like any other object: it's nothing special.

```
var newURL = = document.getElementById('foo').href; // or whatever...
myObject.playlist[0] = newURL;
```

Answer (score 0):

use [ ] i.e square brackets to represent a variable

e.g [temp], where temp is a variable